# PHP Script for counting profile views in a social network

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP but I have made my own social network by reading some books.I want to add something which is not new but still good feature.I want to add profile views.

Suppose User 'ABC' visited user XYZ's profile it should increase count and one time only. Not every time. I have no idea how to keep track of users viewing profiles. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a table with 2 columns of users IDs. The first column for the visitor user and second one for the visited user, like this :

Table : **user_visit**

```
  visitor    visited 
----------|----------|
     1    |     2    |
     3    |     2    |
     3    |     1    |
```

If you do so, you can count the number of rows for particular user to calculate visit count and also you can have the record of which user sees whom.

Comment: This also has the added benefit of allowing you to store your site users' viewing activity in a log of sorts which gives you a metric to look at analytics for your site activity. I might suggest adding a date stamp to the table as well so that you can choose to only look at the last X days, months, years, etc when checking the number of visitors to get a "rolling total". It'll also allow you to easily prune the table if it gets too large without losing all your data.

Comment: Thanks, man. But I really don't know how visiting thing works. Please re read the question again. What's the logic behind knowing if a particular user is viewing another users profile.

Comment: In your question , you're asking about how to keep the count of profile visitors, which is what I answered :)
but if you're talking about checking which users are checking the profile **right now**, I don't know the mechanism exactly.